# DD4T XpmMarkupService Binding Error

Tags: dd4t, 2011-sp1

I am running DD4T 2.1 and when setting up the DI container (Autofac) I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type
>   'DD4T.Mvc.ViewModels.XPM.XpmMarkupService' is not assignable to
>   service 'DD4T.MVC.ViewModels.XPM.IXpmMarkupService'.

Here's the code that does the DI initialization:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
            builder.UseDD4T();
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
            //XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

Can anyone guide me on where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

The type `DD4T.Mvc.ViewModels.XPM.XpmMarkupService` is not assignable to service `DD4T.**MVC**.ViewModels.XPM.IXpmMarkupService` but it is assignable to `DD4T.**Mvc**.ViewModels.XPM.IXpmMarkupService`.

One fix is to download the `DD4T.DI.Autofac` project and modify `Mvc.cs` `RegisterMvc` method to correctly register `XpmMarkupService` as `DD4T.Mvc.ViewModels.XPM.IXpmMarkupService`.

Compile and reference the updated `DD4T.DI.Autofac` dll in your project.

Answer (score 3):

We got the same error but fixed it by simply reverting DDT4T.MVC5 NuGet package to version 2.0.8.

We are also using Autofac v4.1.0 and Autofac.Mvc5 v 4.0.0

Are there any issues we need to be aware of with this fix?